# Does a thread stops executing and contiune? It is just confusing

Tags: android, client-server

I added logs to the code just to understand the order and time of its execution, but so far it is just confusing!

When I execute this code and start the server, I get these outputs

---

"start server", "ServerThread"

"listening", "ServerThread"

"connection arrived", "ServerThread"

---

And stops there, and when I connect to the server I only get

---

"connection accepted", "ServerThread"

---

As if it was hanging on

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

Isn't it suppost to exit the try for some sort of exception and print the whole thing again?

```
class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            Log.e("start server", "ServerThread");
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("IO error at starting server", "ServerThread");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exc at starting server", "ServerThread");
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            Log.e("listening", "ServerThread");
            try {
                Log.e("connection arrived", "ServerThread");
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                Log.e("connection accepted", "ServerThread");
                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(
                        socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("IO error at accept", "ServerThread");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exc at accept", "ServerThread");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a blocker method, it will block until you receive a connection.

take a look at the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()

Comment: So, does it really hang on 'socket = serverSocket.accept();'?

Comment: Yeah, it waits until the next connection is received... it will maintain a port opened listening but no CPU is consumed.

Comment: I am assuming it will be the same case for reading a line, while/interrupt/input.readline, it will hang there till message arrives, when it does, it call whatever code and repeat the loop, right?

Comment: I did not understood well, but in this case, yes, it receiver starts a new thread, loops and go wait again...

Comment: Sorry, the code was not included above, it is about the code that react to the msg sent by client to the server, it has similar structure to the one above, it also seems hangs on till message recived. Thanks

Comment: Take a look on method docs, it always show if it is a blocker method.